# Creating a 4th order Butterworth filter R

Tags: filters, butterworth, r

I have sampled my data at 2000 Hz and want to generate a fourth order low-pass zero-lag filter with a cut-off frequency of 150 Hz.

I have put the code below that I have created but I have the following questions. Given that I have used the `filtfilt` function do I need to change the number to `2` so that it is a second-order and should I also double the cut-off frequency i.e change `W` to 0.3 from 0.15.

```
rawdata = data$`Moment unfiltered`     
bf = butter(4,0.15,type = c("low"), plane = c("z"))
filtereddata = filtfilt(bf, data$`Moment unfiltered`)
```

Answer (score 1):

> do I need to change the number to “2” so that it is a second-order

Yes

> and should I also double the cut-off frequency i.e change “W” to 0.3 from 0.15.

No

Strictly speaking, doubling up the filter will make the gain at the cutoff frequency -6dB instead of -3dB. So you have created a Linkwitz-Riley and not a Butterworth filter.

If you want a gain of exactly -3dB at 150 Hz you would need to increase the frequency slightly. You can work out the math by calculating the -1.5dB point of a Butterworth filter, but trial and error is probably quicker. 185Hz should get you fairly close.

In any case, the shape will still NOT be that of a Butterworth. Cascading two Butterworth filters does not result in another Butterworth filter. The zeros are in the right location but the poles are simply duplicated and are not Butterworth-distributed any more.

Comment: Ahhh I did not know that the frequency had to be slightly different, brilliant, thank you very much. I will change the order to 2 and keep as 0.15 as I am not too confident with the maths side of things.